# how to pass a object which contains List<object> to web service method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to pass one `JBSearchRequest` object which contains `List<JBCredential>` to my asp.net web service. I am able to call this web service from SOAP UI and some other tools but when I'm trying to send request from my C# client code is giving problem.

My Web service class is

```
    public List<JBCredential> JBCredentials{ get; set; }
    public string codes { get; set; }
    public string db { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
```

I've tried the following

```
 test.JBSearchRequest s = new test.JBSearchRequest();
 test.JBCredential jb = new test.JBCredential();
    jb.code = "LNK";
    jb.Username = "";
    jb.Password = "";
    /
    s.query = "java";

    s.mode = "mock_search";
    s.JBCredentials.Add(jb);//I'm not getting add method

      so I've tried like this
    s.JBCredentials[0].code = jb.code;
    s.JBCredentials[0].Password = jb.Password;
    s.JBCredentials[0].Username = jb.Username;
   and also I tried
   List<JBCredential> ad=new List<JBCredential>();
   ad.Add(jb);
   s.JBCredentials=ad;
```

Please help me how to pass object which contains list when we are consuming web service.

Comment: you simply pass it like you normally do. what is the signature of the web service method?

Comment: public List<Search> GetSearchHandle(JBSearchRequest request, RequestArguments args)

Comment: Where's the `List<object>`? I see `List<JBCredential>`.

Comment: It is List<JBCredential> only

Comment: you dont specify what the name of the actualy webservice instance is, nor are you giving it RequestArguments. you also dont define what "s" is in terms of its properties and what it exposes. please post the FULL code.

Comment: test.JBSearchRequest s = new test.JBSearchRequest(); for this class I'm creating instance.